# JUnit TestCase Failure

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, junit

I'am running my JunitTest and it gives the following error.. not failure.

```
 Error creating bean with name 'reportDAO' defined in class path resource [LT.xml]:
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate';
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in class path resource [LT.xml]: 
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [LT.xml]: 
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: 
 Association references unmapped class: dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.model.engine.result.BDTSTest
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:978)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:462)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:404)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:375)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:263)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:170)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:260)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:184)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:163)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:430)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
 at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.createApplicationContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:199)
 at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContextLocations(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:179)
 at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:158)
 at org.springframework.test.AbstractSpringContextTests.getContext(AbstractSpringContextTests.java:105)
 at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.setUp(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:87)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
 at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:69)
 at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
 at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
 at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
 at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
 at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I checked my respective xml files all references are present in those xml files, I couldn't find where the problem is. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To help you further, we probably need to see the unit test code and know the version of spring you are using.
 My initial quess would be, that you have not indicated the configuration file location with **@ContextConfiguration** annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mapping of one of your domain class is incorrect. Are you using XML Based or Annotation Based Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The class dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.model.engine.result.BDTSTest is not present the file persistence.xml
Are you using `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` in persistence.xml? 
If that the case, you nedd to map all Entity classes manually.